# WooCommerce - change price of item in cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, add-filter

I'm building a plugin "Buy for xxx and get a free gift".

Everything works fine, but when I add the gift to cart, the price is 0, but in the subtotal I still see the price with "free product" price included.

Ie., I have items worth $200 and I'm eligible to get a free gift. I pick it and the gift is added to cart. The price is 0. But in the subtotal, I still see price of the items + free gift.

I set the price in `before_calculate_totals` hook like this:

```
    foreach ($cart as $key => $item) {
        if (isset($item['_wfg_gift']) && $item['_wfg_gift'] == 1) {
            $item['data']->set_price(0);
        }
    }
```

I also tried the `calculate_totals` hook with no luck. I cannot use the `get_price` filter, as user might want to buy the same product, that is offered as free gift.

What is the way to set cart item price, so it works in cart, subtotal and total?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

"woocommerce_before_calculate_totals" this action is used to update the cart item price.

Please check your condition in code by debugging it.

Do you want to set "0" for only "Free Item" or set "0" to entire cart?

Comment: I'm setting the price correctly afaik, in the cart there's 0, but in the subtotal the price is counted... No idea what's going on here..